# Inertia+Vue3, How to get the value of a ref property and pass it as a route() parameter?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs, ziggy

I need to get the value of a ref property, and pass this value in the <Link :route()> parameter

My code in Component.vue

```
<div class="item" v-for="item in props.user.items" :key="item.id">

<Link :href="route('user.route', {id: item.id, ll: getCurrentRef() })">Go to edit</Link>

<div>
<TextInput type="number" :id="`ll_${item.id}`" name="ll" :value="item.ll?0"
@keyup="setCurrentRef($event.target.value);" />
</div>

</div>

<input type="text" ref="element" id="element" value="XX">

<script setup>
import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue';

const element = ref(null)

const setCurrentRef = (value) => {
    element.value.value = value;
}

const getCurrentRef = () => {
    return element.value.value = value;
}

onMounted(() => {
    //alert(element.value.value)
});
```

I can set the value of the ref element in @keyup with the setCurrentRef() method normally, but I'm not getting the value with the getCurrentRef() method

In onMounted when I refresh the page, I see the first value of the element which is "XXX", but if you put this return "alert(element.value.value)" in a function and call it anywhere, this returns a alert with "undefined"

In the console, the error that appears is: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: value is not defined.

Searching, I didn't find anything that would help me resolve this.